# How can I create multiple Mapbox variables out of a for loop given a list of coordinates

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, mapbox

```
function mapping() {
    var marker0 = new mapboxgl.Marker()
        .setLngLat(mainCoords[0])
        .addTo(map);
    var marker1 = new mapboxgl.Marker()
        .setLngLat(mainCoords[1])
        .addTo(map);
}
```

How can I have this continue on for as long as mainCoords.length this? I guess the real question is how can I make a bunch of variables with the final piece of is as (i) example: marker(i).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just use an array and push all markers in there:

```js
function mapping() {
  var mappings = [];
  var mainCoords= [
      [1, 1],
      [2, 2],
      [3, 3]
    ],
    for (var i = 0; i < mainCoords.length; i++) {
      mappings.push(
        new mapboxgl.Marker()
        .setLngLat(mainCoords[i])
        .addTo(map)
      );
    }
  return mappings;
}

var markers = mapping();
console.log("First marker: ", markers[0]);
console.log("Second marker: ", markers[1]);
```

Comment: Perfect, so just to clarify what's happening, this is adding each object into an array?

Comment: Yes, it's adding each resulting marker into an array which can be retrieved by using the same index as the `coordinate` in `mainCoords`